# Angular 4, difference between httpClient and HttpClientModule

Tags: angular, asynchronous, behaviorsubject, angular4-httpclient

In this article [here](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/the-new-http-client-in-angular-4-3-754bd3ff83a8) and others :It looks like you need to import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts and HttpClient in app.component.ts  to make a http request. Why? How do they work?

Comment: The second part could be a new question

Comment: Do you think I should edit out the second part and make another post?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In simple words,

You can call HttpClientModule as a "feature-bundle" that comes as a core part in Angular. In this "feature-bundle", you have many other small features like HttpClient (in Angular language, it's "service"), Interceptors etc.

In order for you to use these "feature(s)", you need to import the "feature-bundle" inside your main module (in your case, Angular's AppModule) so that, you have access to HttpClient and many other services inside your working component.

**One liner:**

> HttpClient is a angular service bundled inside
>   HttpClientModule.

Comment: That explains it. Tentatively marked it as the best answer. Gonna wait a little  and see if anyone wanna fill in on the 2nd question. (or make another post for that). Thank you.

Comment: Better to have another post for 2nd question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but then why is the address same for both, i mean why doesn't the import statement for "`HttpClient`" look like this " `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http/HttpClientModule'` "